# Implementing a C++ range-for wrapper for lvalues and rvalues

Tags: c++, qt, for-loop, c++17, rvalue-reference

I've implemented a little helper wrapper for range-for loops that allows iterating over both keys and values of the associative Qt containers like `QMap` and `QHash`, extracting each pair as a structured binding, e.g.:

```
const QMap<int, QString> digitMap = { {1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"} };
for (auto [intKey, strVal] : make_keyval(digitMap)) {
    qDebug() << intKey << "->" << strVal;
}
```

This isn't supported out-of-the-box for the Qt containers as they require using a specific pair of `constKeyValueBegin()` and `constKeyValueEnd()` methods (let's assume only non-mutating iterations). So my idea was to write a simple wrapper type that provides a pair of regular `begin()` and `end()` methods which simply call the keyValue ones on the container.

That's easy enough, but as a stretch goal I also wanted to make the wrapper usable with temporaries, like `make_keyval(sometype.toMap())`. The main challenge there was extending the lifetime of the temporary through the end of the iteration, as I'm going through a proxy object. Here's the solution I came up with:

```
template<typename C>
struct key_value_range_iterator {
    key_value_range_iterator(const C& container) : m_rvalueContainer(nullptr), m_containerRef(container) {}
    key_value_range_iterator(const C&& container) : m_rvalueContainer(std::make_unique<C>(std::move(container))), m_containerRef(*m_rvalueContainer) {}

    typename C::const_key_value_iterator begin() const { return m_containerRef.constKeyValueBegin(); }
    typename C::const_key_value_iterator end() const { return m_containerRef.constKeyValueEnd(); }

private:
    const std::unique_ptr<C> m_rvalueContainer;
    const C& m_containerRef;
};

template<typename C>
auto make_keyval(C&& container) { return key_value_range_iterator(std::forward<C>(container)); }
```

This seems to work fine for both regular variables and temporaries. For temporaries, `m_rvalueContainer` is used to store the moved temporary for the duration of the iteration, then it's referenced by `m_containerRef`. In the regular variable case, we just store the lvalue reference in `m_containerRef` directly leaving `m_rvalueContainer` unset. I verified the right constructor gets called in each case, and that the temporary only gets destroyed after the range-for loop completes.

So my question is simply: is this a correct implementation for my wrapper, or did I miss something? Or maybe there's a corner case I haven't thought of?

Note that in my initial version, I had `m_rvalueContainer` as a regular value, but I figured this would end up instantiating an empty container for nothing in the lvalue case (though that's a cheap operation for Qt containers), so I replaced it with `unique_ptr` to ensure there's no overhead in that case. Yes, it still ends up initializing it to nullptr, but that's neglectable.

Any other comments or recommendations?

Comment: Isn't the temporary `sometype.toMap()` held until the end of the range-for loop? Is all this "machinery" needed?

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk The temporary returned by sometype.toMap() does not have a `begin/end` function, so we need to wrap it. That means the wrappers lifetime will be extended in this case, not the container. So the wrapper needs to take responsibility to extend the lifetime of the container if it's an rvalue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `make_keyval` knows if the object passed in is lvalue or rvalue, you can pass that parameter on to your wrapper.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename C>
struct key_value_range_iterator {
    key_value_range_iterator(const C container) : m_containerRef(container) {}

    using iterator = typename std::remove_reference_t<C>::const_key_value_iterator;

    iterator begin() const { return m_containerRef.constKeyValueBegin(); }
    iterator end() const { return m_containerRef.constKeyValueEnd(); }

private:
    const C m_containerRef;
};

template<typename C>
auto make_keyval(C&& container) { return key_value_range_iterator<C>(std::forward<C>(container)); }
```

When passing an lvalue `C` is deduces as `QMap&` making the wrapper hold a reference.
When passing an rvalue `C` is deduces as `QMap` making the wrapper move the rvalue into it's member.

Since `C` can be `QMap&` we need to use `std::remove_reference` to obtain the iterator type succesfully for the lvalue case.

Comment: is this really needed? I mean `for (auto x : foo_returns_a_container())` is also fine

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yes, but OP is not looking to return a container. He wants to return a wrapper for a container, and in that case we need to store a reference to the original container in our wrapper. If the original is an rvalue, we need to make sure the reference is not dangling.

Comment: hm ok it is rather `for (auto x : create_wrapper( return_container() ))` but I dont really understand when the lifetime of the temporary ends.

Comment: the temporary will be passed to the constructor of the wrapper and be destroyed after the wrapper has been constructed. The fact that we store a reference to the temporary inside the wrapper will not extend it's lifetime.

Comment: yes got it, had to read [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) several times before I understood ;)

Comment: "This problem may be worked around using init-statement (C++20)"

Comment: Are you trying to reimplement [QKeyValueIterator](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeyvalueiterator.html)?

Comment: @chehrlic Seems like it. I've never used Qt myself, so not familiar with what it has. I'm just answering the question. Even though that class does not solve the issue of using an rvalue. You would need to use an init-statement or store the container in a variable before looping it.

Comment: @super thanks a lot for the feedback and your suggestion!

"When passing an lvalue C is deduces as QMap& making the wrapper hold a reference. When passing an rvalue C is deduces as QMap making the wrapper move the rvalue into it's member."

I didn't know that was the standard deduction behavior for lvalues vs rvalues. Do you happen to have a link for that behavior? Not that I don't trust you, but I wouldn't even know where to go looking for that stuff without reading through hours of specs :)

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk emphasis on the "may be worked around". I personally don't find it a convenient alternative. My goal was to use the wrapper the exact same way I would use a container directly. But you're still correct that it's one way to address the temporary case.

Comment: @chehrlic Not at all. In fact, I'm *using* QKeyValueIterator inside the wrapper. But QKeyValueIterator itself doesn't make QMap/QHash container usable in a range-for loop.  My wrapper adds the missing part to link the two.

Comment: @super Ah, I think I found it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction, section "Deduction from a function call", points 3) and 4):
" If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter (so-called forwarding reference), and the corresponding function call argument is an lvalue, the type lvalue reference to A is used in place of A for deduction (Note: this is the basis for the action of std::forward Note: in class template argument deduction, template parameter of a class template is never a forwarding reference (since C++17))"
Is that the one?

Comment: @super Ok I tried it with MSVC2019 and it does work as you describe. I found one small difference between your implementation and mine though: in the rvalue case `m_containerRef(container)` calls the copy constructor rather than the move constructor. I've tried adding `std::forward` but couldn't make it work for both lvalues and rvalues with a single constructor (outside of using `std::enable_if`). But I don't consider it an issue since Qt containers support shallow-copy anyway, so I'm still accepting your answer and thank you again for pointing me to that deduction rule.

Comment: @RomainPokrzywka If you want the container to be moved in the rvalue case you can change the constructor to `key_value_range_iterator(const C&& container) : m_containerRef(std::forward<C>(container)) {}`. If `C` is `QMap&`, it will be `const QMap&&&` and reference collapsing will make it `QMap&`, for `QMap` you will get an rvalue reference, `QMap&&`. `std::forward` will move in the rvalue case.

Comment: @RomainPokrzywka [This section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) also seems relevant.